# Is it correct or not array.concat() method

Tags: javascript, arrays

I created  concat function similar to Array.concat(). It is passing all my tests:

1. return new array only passing array argument.
2. passing two parameters second one is string.
3. passing two parameters second one is array.
4. passing two parameters second one is number.
5. passing three parameters second is number, third is string.
6. passing four arguments.

```
function concat() {
  var result = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    result.push(arguments[i]);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: You could just do `[1,2,3]` instead of `concat(1,2,3)`, but I suppose if you wanted to have a function for that your implementation works. The name is confusing, though, as it does not concatenate arrays. It just creates an array of the function arguments.

Comment: Should be moved to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Thilo what if instead of `1, 2, 3`, you have three variables  - `a, b, c`? `concat([1, 2, 3], 4, [5, 6])` should behave differently than `[[1, 2, 3], 4, [5, 6]]` EDIT: Saying that, OP's implementation doesn't do what Array.concat does, as it doesn't flatten the arrays.

Comment: @VLAZ  Well, this implementation does not flatten the nested array if that is what you wanted. (That's why I said the name is confusing. It does *not* concatenate arrays. It just returns the functions arguments back).

Comment: @Thilo yeah, I added this to my comment. So, to me, this doesn't seem like a correct `concat` implementation. After all, it doesn't *behave* like `concat`. So, this really is a question for OP - what should be considered "correct" here? It passes the tests listed, which means it's correct as far as the listed tests are concerned. Which is pretty much circular reasoning, though - it's correct because it's correct. But what is the definition to judge correctness?

Comment: I'd like to see the expected result for the first test case before I say it works as expected. Even if it does, it is a) misleadingly named and b) duplicates the existing functionality of `[1,2,3]` so I don't think it should pass code review.

Answer (score 0):

This is more like `Array.of` as mentioned in comments:

```js
console.log(Array.of(1, 2, 3));
```

But you can make the exact same functionality much more concise with rest parameters and the implicit return of arrow functions:

```js
const concat = (...a) => a;
console.log(concat());
console.log(concat(1, 2, 3));
```

Although, since it *is* `Array.of`, it's so much easier just to assign the function reference:

```js
const concat = Array.of;
console.log(concat());
console.log(concat(1, 2, 3));
```

Comment: It is not really similar to the "normal" `concat` method. It does not concatenate arrays at all. They remain "unflattened". If anything, it is similar (identical?) to the built-in `Array(1,2,3)` method.

Comment: This is  pretty much an array construction implementation.

Comment: @Thilo not *completely* identical. Annoyingly `Array(1)` and `Array(1, 2)` have different effects - the first creates an *empty* array, the other an array with two members. I hate the array constructor, it's so annoying to use because of this.

Comment: This is actually [`Array.of()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/of). The [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) constructor actually does more than this.

Comment: Ok, I'll add that @Thilo.